# Swift Charts delay for realtime data

Tags: swift, charts

I am using [Swift 5 with Charts 3.6.0](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Charts) ( [Line Chart - cubic lines](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/35e53886f3682ef0aea90b07b0a45a96ac8597e9b7d41be8dc753f50786ef3f9/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f5068696c4a61792f4d5043686172742f6d61737465722f73637265656e73686f74732f63756269636c696e6563686172742e706e67) ) to plot real-time watchOS core motion. The goal is to display watch movement as quickly as possible. Since my sample rate is high, I suspect there will be a bottleneck in updating the view, and as such, would only like to display N most recent items.

Here is the watch function that sends the data immediately, as mentioned in [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615617-sendmessagedata), and numerous [tutorials](https://medium.com/@litoarias/watchos-5-part-2-communication-between-iphone-and-apple-watch-and-vice-versa-ced41f453b11):

```
motion.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 120.0
motion.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: .xArbitraryZVertical, to: queue) { [self] (deviceMotion: CMDeviceMotion?, _ : Error?) in
    guard let motion = deviceMotion else { return }
    self.sendDataToPhone(quaternion: motion.attitude.quaternion, time: Double(Date().timeIntervalSince1970))
}

private func sendDataToPhone(quaternion: CMQuaternion, time: Double) {
    if WCSession.default.isReachable {
        WCSession.default.sendMessageData(try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: [quaternion.x, quaternion.y, quaternion.z, quaternion.w, time], requiringSecureCoding: false), replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: nil);
    }
}
```

Once received, the packets are interpreted by the session() function on the iPhone:

```
onViewDidLoad() {
    self.lineChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = -1;
    self.lineChartView.leftAxis.axisMaximum = 1;
}

func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessageData messageData: Data) {
    let record : [Double] = try! NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [NSArray.self], from: messageData) as! [Double]
    laggyFunction(qaternions: [simd_quatd.init(ix: record[0], iy: record[1], iz: record[2], r: record[3])], quaternionTimes: [record[4]])
}


private func laggyFunction(qaternions: [simd_quatd], quaternionTimes: [Double]) {
    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        let dataset = self.lineChartView.data!.getDataSetByIndex(0)!
        var x = dataset.entryCount + 1;
        for quaternion in qaternions {
            let _ = dataset.addEntry(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(x), y: quaternion.vector.w))
            x += 1;
        }
        
        // limit the amount of points
        while (dataset.entryCount > 5) {
            let _ = dataset.removeFirst()
        }

        // - re index so entries start from 1
        for startIdx in 1..<dataset.entryCount { 
            dataset.entryForIndex(startIdx - 1)!.x = Double(startIdx); 
        }
        

        self.lineChartView.data!.notifyDataChanged()
        self.lineChartView.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

**Logic flow:**

As packets come in, new entries are added to the initial dataset from the lineChartView. In the event there are more than 5, first N are removed. Then, the x values are re-indexed on the chart to ensure a sequential flow.

**The problem:**

The delay in updating the UI chart is very high. The elapsed time of both functions to complete is plotted below. At the 73rd percentile, the laggy function is able to accommodate the sample rate of incoming packets ( < 1/120 = 0.008) . The session function seems to accommodate the sample rate throughout. The CDF plot, in my opinion, does not do it justice. Visually, the chart is very "sluggish". As an experiment, if I throw the watch against the wall, I can observe it hitting the concrete well before the chart is updated.

My goal is to update the Chart as quickly as possible to observe watch motion and discard new entries until the UI is updated. What is the correct way to do this with my chart choice?

[image]

Comment: Did you try DispatchQueue.main.async instead of DispatchQueue.main.sync ?

Comment: @NikolayTabunchenko I have, no visual observations. ( I have to incorporate block operations, or similar techniques, to discard old messages. If I lower the sample rate to 60Hz, smooth as butter. Doubling it seems to cause such large overhead )